# Internet Connection sharing with any AT&T MVNO

Tags: 8.1, windows-10

I have an unlocked AT&T 1020, an unlocked T-Mobile 521, and a Verizon 928 (not sure if it's unlocked, but it's worked with T-Mobile and Consumer Cellular).  I'm using Consumer Cellular, an AT&T MVNO.  Has anyone gotten internet sharing to work with Consumer Cellular or any other AT&T MVNO?

I KNOW that internet sharing worked on the 928 back when I was with Verizon. I've tried with the 928 both with WP 8.1 and WP10.  On all three phones I get a message saying that I should go to AT&T's website or call 611 to set it up.

I've seen and tried various tricks, such as installing a non-English keyboard.  I've seen a hack that involved using a non US SIM card to turn it on, but I can't see how that would work for the 928, since internet sharing used to work on it.

I've had to manually enter apn settings on each phone to get them to work with Consumer Cellular, so I have access point on all three phones.